# WP disable Js SuperFish style

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on WP web site, I want to change Superfish sub-menu style(position) but the problem is that The Superfish JS(which is incorporated on WP template) does not allow me to do this change with my custom JS or CSS using (!important),Superfish always applies his style `<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;margin-left: 310px; margin-top: -23px">` when mouse hover on menu-item-1256 to get sub-menu, how can I change that to:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 0px;">
```

I tried to put this custom JS but not work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".sub-menu"").css("margin-left", "100px";"margin-top", "0px";);

});
```

How Can I disable the style added by Superfish to put my own style ?

Thank you very much!

menu-item-1256 code :

```
<li id="menu-item-1256" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1256">
<a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">PROFESSIONNELLE</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; margin-left: 310px; margin-top: -23px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed the problem with !import on css